# Is it possible to instrument Java byte code in REST application?

Tags: java, javassist

On a simple standalone application i am able to implement the Java Instrumentation using JavaAssist library (http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-instrumentation/). Is it possible to do the same on REST application? If so how can we run the JVM with “-javaagent" in REST application

Comment: How do you start your server (or, for which server)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am just testing on a sample Hello World application, starting the server(tomcat) from my Intellij IDE